# How to maintain page scope in my spring controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session-variables

I have both form and result table on the same page . This page is backed by single @Controller.

When user accesses page(GET) I store attributes in session scope so that they are available after form submission(I do page reload on POST).

When user leaves this page I need somehow to remove session-scoped attributes.

Is there a way in spring 3 mvc to handle request that leaves my page?

Answer (score 1):

You can give your scope to controller by using `@Scope` annotation.

```
@Controller(value="mycontroller")
@Scope("session")
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController
{
    int count = 0;
    public ModelAndView  printHello(HttpServletRequest request) {
        count++;
        ModelAndView mymodelview = new ModelAndView("success");
        mymodelview.addObject(`enter code here`"count", count);
   }
}
```

if the scope is request(`@Scope("request")`) then every time the value of count is 1 where as if the scope is session then for a particular session the count value will increase by one.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just POST, then you don't need to store them in the session. 
You can set your model in get method `model.addAttribute("bean", BeanClass);`
and then when you post the page, you will have that bean class:

```
> public String postMethod(@ModelAttribute("bean") BeanClass 
>           bean, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) 
>           throws Exception { 
>     //... 
> }
```